# Jenkins Copy-Item via PowerShell Plugin

Tags: powershell, session, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

#### Problem

Edited (8/31/2017): For Better Clarification

So I am working on a script that needs to copy files from within the Jenkins Workspace and place the copy on a targeted Server(s) designated by the user. These servers also require that the user enter their DomainUserName and Password so that these servers can be accessed. As such, I have found myself struggling to perform a simple copy/paste between these two(or more) points.

I have tried a number of things utilizing the PowerShell Plugin in hopes of achieving this task, but none have panned out.

I have attempted to begin an `Invoke-Command` session to the targeted server; however, once inside this session, it no longer understands what the Jenkins environment is and thus loses scope of Jenkins preventing me from calling to it in any simple means (that I can think of).

I have attempted to pass down `-ArgumentList` items in hopes of maintaining the integrity of the file locations; however, once inside the session, it tries to apply that location to the server I am in a session with. Example: I pass in the file locations as an Argument into the `Invoke-Command` and write a `Copy-Item` statement using that argument as the `-Path`; however, when the code gets translated at run-time, it sees the path as `C:\file\to\be\copied` and attempts to find that location on the Server rather than from the Jenkins Workspace.

I have tried to perform the following:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\JenkinsServerIP\C$\Expected\Path" -Destination C:\Targeted\Path
# or reverse of above
Copy-Item -Path "$env:Workspace\Expected\Path" -Destination "\\$serverAddress\C$\targeted\Path"
```

Which has failed too.

I found that PowerShell v5 and greater have a feature for `Copy-Item` that lets you copy `-FromSession` and `-ToSession` . Unfortunately... I have also found that this is not supported by the PS Plugin for Jenkins... as of yet.

```
# Thus, this following 'easy' example will not work
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $targetComputer -Credentials $cred
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Original\Path\" -Destination "C:\Target\Path\" -ToSession $session
```

I am running out of ideas and I cannot find much in the way of research for this problem...

#### Question

Does anyone know how to setup a `Copy-Item` within the Jenkins PowerShell Plugin that would allow me to copy specific contents of the Jenkins Workspace and and past that onto a targeted server/machine?

Please note: New software requires approval and Archiving is also not an option

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a direct answer, I'll assume you're also using the `pipeline` plugin and tell how I do it. Perhaps I might give you an idea...

For copying files I ditched PowerShell and now use either of these options:

For exchanging files between nodes: use `stash`/`unstash`, which is easy and reliable for small files.
For copying from some remote machine: use a batch script to map a network like so:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: yourCredential, usernameVariable: 'REMOTE_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'REMOTE_PASSWORD')]) {

  def source = 'XX.XX.10.2\\Expected\\File\\Path'
  def destination = 'C:\\direct\\path'
  # Some arbitrary drive letter not currently in use...
  def netDrive = 'n:'

  try {
    bat "net use $netDrive \"$source\" ${env.REMOTE_PASSWORD} /u:${env.REMOTE_USERNAME}"

    # Run your script here. You can either write it directly or use readFile to load it into a variable
    powerShell 'Your-Script'
  }
  catch (e) {
    print e.getMessage()
    print e.getStackTrace()
  }
  finally {
    bat "net use /d $netDrive"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I am not well versed in Batch scripting. Would you mind explaining this a little example a little more for me? For example, do I replace `usernameVariable` with say `env.DomainUser` (variable declared in Jenkins)? How would I call to this networked drive once I am in my PowerShell script? Thank you in advance

Comment: Sure :) Actually, using the `withCredentials` block allows you to hide the username and password from the build's log. In order to use it you need to create a username/password crendential in Jenkins' credential manager (and name it using the `id` field). For the sake of simplicity you can indeed write `${env.DomainUser}` to get that environment variable.

In your script you call the network drive like any ordinary drive: in this example it would be `Copy-Path n:\subdir c:\direct\path`